# Can I run Python Django and Ruby on the same Apache server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I'm runnig Python Django on Apache2 with ModWSGI and I would like to run Ruby on Rails on the same server.

Is it possible do this?

I read that Passenger for Ruby on Rails can support Django too.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've done it. I would not suggest doing it for a server that is busy or prone to load spikes because of the way these modules work, they embed code into the server process itself (though mod_wsgi is better than mod_python for this).

When I do HEAD http://my.dev.server the response headers include this:
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/2.2.15 PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.10 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/1.3 Python/2.5.2

For example, if you have 40 apache child processes adding mod_wsgi may add a couple megs of RAM to each, so used RAM may go up by 100MB. Adding phusion passenger made cause each child to use another 5 MB of RAM increasing it by 200MB more.

However, if you have 10 apache child processes this is not a huge deal.

If you are on a server that gets these busy periods then one way to achieve better results is to use nginx instead of Apache (or fastcgi with apache). It does not embed any of the application code into the http process.

Comment: The mod_wsgi module itself should not add a couple of megs of ram to each process so long as you don't have a borked Python installation which doesn't supply a shared library. You can also run daemon mode to ensure your application runs distinct from Apache child processes. In the latter you can ensure Python doesn't even get initialised at all in Apache child processes. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/11/save-on-memory-with-modwsgi-30.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html